# Select2 4.0.3 Ajax always returning 'Result not found'

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use select2 ajax so results will only show once a user types.

Here's my select2 code:

```
$("#itemize_tracking_no").select2({ 
    placeholder: "Courier Tracking #", 
    debug: true, 
    minimumInputLength: 2, 
    allowClear: true, 
    delay: 250, 
    ajax: { 
        url: "ajax_tracking_no", 
        dataType: 'json', 
        type: "GET",
        data: function (params) { 
            return {
                term: params.term
            };
        }, 
        processResults: function(data, params){
            return {
                results: $.map(data.courier_tracking_no, function(courier_tracking_no){
                    return { id: courier_tracking_no.id, text: courier_tracking_no.courier_tracking_no }
                })
            };
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }
    } 
});
```

My JSON response:

```
    {"result":[
        {"id":"1","courier_tracking_no":"4800417009445"},
        {"id":"9","courier_tracking_no":"6954176812345"},
        {"id":"22","courier_tracking_no":"wetweg"},
        {"id":"26","courier_tracking_no":"JM001PCS"},
        {"id":"27","courier_tracking_no":"9092501010017"},
        {"id":"28","courier_tracking_no":"4806513103018"},
        {"id":"29","courier_tracking_no":"4801981112005"},
        {"id":"30","courier_tracking_no":"4800047820182"},
        {"id":"31","courier_tracking_no":"Test01"},
        {"id":"32","courier_tracking_no":"Test02"},
        {"id":"33","courier_tracking_no":"Test03"},
        {"id":"35","courier_tracking_no":"Test00001"}
        ]
    }
```

When I type `wet` which should produce `{"id":"22","courier_tracking_no":"wetweg"}`, instead it says `No results found`

What could be my error?

I'll be grateful for your help. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to return { id: courier_tracking_no.id, courier_tracking_no: courier_tracking_no.courier_tracking_no }

Answer (score 0):

**[This](http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/codeigniter-3-select2-ajax-autocomplete-from-database-example-with-demoexample.html)** did the trick for me. I haven't thought that my case is different since I'm using it with **CodeIgniter**. I just modified my code to get data in the model instead of loading the database in controller.